# Añadir return en Alamofire Swift

Tags: swift, swift2, post, asincronismo, alamofire

Tengo una funcion que realiza una petición post a un servidor para comprobar si un usuario esta registrado o no.

Para ello utilizo `Alamofire`

```
func isFullRegister() -> Bool {
    let urlString: String = "http://url_que_utilizo"
    var bool: Bool = false
    var json: JSON?

    let cadenaCodificar = ""
    cadenaParametros = codificarBase64(cadenaCodificar)
    let parametros = ["param_uno": var1, "param_dos": cadenaParametros]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, urlString, parameters: parametros).responseJSON { response in
        if let respuesta = response.data {
            json = JSON(data: respuesta)
            if json![0]["error"] != "no" || json![0]["nombre"] == "" {
                print("*****FALSE*****")
                bool = false//no esta registrado en la plataforma
            }
            else {
                print("*****TRUE*****")
                bool = true//Si esta registrado0 en la plataforma
            }
        }
    }
    print(bool)
    return bool
}
```

El problema es que hace el return antes de que acabe la petición `POST`

Me muestra esto por consola:

```
false
*****TRUE*****
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que al hacer el POST lo haces de forma asíncrona. Esto quiere decir que el flujo del programa se separa. Se queda por un lado haciendo el POST y continua para abajo.
Para solucionar eso hay que recurrir a un bloque de completado o completion block.

```
func isFullRegister(completion:(Bool) -> Void ){ //Fijate aquí como queda la cabecera de tu función
   let urlString: String = "http://url_que_utilizo"
   var bool: Bool = false
   var json: JSON?

   let cadenaCodificar = ""
   cadenaParametros = codificarBase64(cadenaCodificar)
   let parametros = ["param_uno": var1, "param_dos": cadenaParametros]

   Alamofire.request(.POST, urlString, parameters: parametros).responseJSON { response in
       if let respuesta = response.data {
           json = JSON(data: respuesta)
           if json![0]["error"] != "no" || json![0]["nombre"] == "" {
               completion(false) //Fijate aquí como se devuelve el completado
           }
           else {
               completion(true) //Fijate aquí como se devuelve el completado
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Luego para usar esta función en modo síncrono que es como a ti te interesa debes hacer esto en el lugar donde uses la función:

```
isFullRegister(){ (respuesta) in
   print(respuesta)
   //Aqui iria tu código en modo síncrono con la función...
}
```

Espero que lo entiendas medio que... No se explicarlo mejor por aquí...